# Can I have two different SSL certificates for main and subdomain?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, ssl-certificate, bitnami

Can I use let's encrypt SSL certificate for main domain (www.example.com) and free amazon ssl certificate for (api.example.com)? Because I am using EC2 instance without application load balancer (ELB) for www.example.com. But for api.example.com, I am using application load balancer (ELB) and connects with EC2 instance. Do you think I can to do that? I am new to it.

Any suggestion appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. There is nothing stopping you from creating all the SSL certificates you want.

Comment: Great! Thank you for the info. Can't wait to setup with my projects.